# Force close a socket if is open

Tags: java, android, sockets

In android app, sometimes the app gets force closed. However, the server socket remains in use. So, the next time I start the app, it gives me the error

> java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in
>   use)

My code to start a socket is

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); // <-- create an unbound socket first
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_PORT))
```

I wish to make sure, that when my restarts.. It should re-use the socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your app is being forced to close because of an uncontrolled exception. Ideally, you should fix whatever problem is forcing your app to close instead of searching for a workaround.

In any case, you should always use `finally` blocks to close your resources, this way they will get closed even if an exception arises.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); // <-- create an unbound socket first
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_PORT));
    // Do your server stuff
} finally {
    if (serverSocket != null) {
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Or better, use try-with-resources if possible (Java 7+):

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();) {
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_PORT));
    // Do your server stuff
}
```

Note that you cannot force close an existing socket that belongs to another process without root permissions.